# Build failed in Add-On Builder when writing to file code is commented

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I try to build my addon, but when I have commented code from this page
[writing to a file example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Writing_to_a_file)
I got `XPI not built`.

This is code, which I have commented:

```
/*
function saveFile(file, data)
{
    Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
    Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

    var ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file)

    var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
    converter.charset = "UTF-8";
    var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(data);

    // The last argument (the callback) is optional.
    NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(status) {
        if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
        // Handle error!
        return;
    }

    // Data has been written to the file.
    });    
}
*/
```

If I remove this code (or whole comment block) build will succeed.

Here is link to this addon: [addon](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/157767/revision/53/)

What's the problem?
Thank you.

Edit:
I have Firefox 15.0.1. Update to 16.0.1 doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was through keyword `Components`. I've solved this problem, replacing this word with `C`, but I've added C as required chrome:

```
var {Cc, Ci, Cu, C} = require("chrome");
```

Now I can compile addon and execute commented function.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings this really helps others!